# How we can edit domain password policy using DotNet

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, active-directory

Is there any way to edit the domain password policy using the c# program? I want to change my domain password policy using my application. Each suggestion or solution is helpful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at System.DirectoryServices namespace

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have gone through it but I didn't get anything helpful in that.